# Formato de fecha y hora en html

Tags: php, html, datetime

Hola comunidad quisiera poder imprimir la fecha y hora como se ve en mi formulario
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando lo agrego al value no sale nada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y tambien quiero que deje de salir asi como input pero con el formato bien

Asi esta mi linea de html

```
 <input name="FechaPedido" value="' . $FechaPedido . '" type="datetime-local" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" >
```

Si me pueden apoyar se los agradecería
También quisiera que se imprima automáticamente la fecha y hora del ordenador en el registro

Comment: haz un `echo` a tu variable `$FechaPedido` y menciona qué es lo que te trae.

Comment: trae la fecha que capture en este formato 2023-04-10 09:13:00.000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dices que `$FechaPedido` te trae `2023-04-10 09:13:00.000000`, entonces hagamos un ejemplo en JS.

Tratemos de setear el valor de tu variable al input de tipo `datetime-local`:

```js
var input = document.getElementsByClassName("input-date")[0];
input.value = "2023-04-10 09:13:00.000000";
console.log("valor del input: ", input.value);
```

```html
<input name="FechaPedido" type="datetime-local" class="form-control datetimepicker-input input-date">
```

Vemos que no se ve el valor porque el formato de fecha no es el correcto, debemos transformarlo en el formato [**ISO 8601**](https://www.progress.com/blogs/understanding-iso-8601-date-and-time-format#:%7E:text=ISO%208601%20Formats&text=ISO%208601%20represents%20date%20and,%E2%80%94more%20on%20that%20below.). Para hacerlo, usamos la función `toISOString()` del objeto `Date()`:

```js
var fecha = new Date("2023-04-10 09:13:00.000000");
result = fecha.toISOString();
console.log("valor del input: ", result);
```

Y usamos `slice(0, 16)` para tener los primeros `16` caracteres (omitir los milisegundos) y así tener el formato correcto para setear al input:

```js
var input = document.getElementsByClassName("input-date")[0];
var fecha = new Date("2023-04-10 09:13:00.000000");
input.value = fecha.toISOString().slice(0, 16);
console.log("valor del input: ", input.value);
```

```html
<input name="FechaPedido" type="datetime-local" class="form-control datetimepicker-input input-date">
```

Y debido a que usas PHP, fácilmente pones el valor `$FechaPedido` en un `div` oculto y lo capturas con `getElementById("").textContent` desde JS, ejemplo:

```js
var input = document.getElementsByClassName("input-date")[0];
var mivariable = document.getElementById("mivariable").textContent;
var fecha = new Date(mivariable);
input.value = fecha.toISOString().slice(0, 16);
console.log("valor del input: ", input.value);
```

```html
<div id="mivariable" style="display: none">2023-04-10 09:13:00.000000</div> <!-- dentro de este div va lo que contiene tu variable -->
<input name="FechaPedido" type="datetime-local" class="form-control datetimepicker-input input-date">
```

Solo reemplazas el texto `2023-04-10 09:13:00.000000` del `div` por `<?php echo $FechaPedido ?>`.

Comment: Acabo de ver que el problema del formato estaba en mi base de datos :o

Comment: Oh... entiendo, pero para ambos casos, ya tienes la solución ;-)